# Can't set an application icon

Tags: android, drawable, android-icons

I've put a PNG image inside `/res/drawable` and specified it in the manifest, but Eclipse throws an error saying `No resource found`.

I've searched everywhere, and can't seem to find an answer to this.

The filename appears in autocomplete too, without the extension.

**Edit**:The icon's filename is ic_menu_umbrella.png

and here's how it appears in the manifest

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_umbrella">
```

Comment: please show location of icon in /res/drawable and relevant manifest lines.

Comment: I think you should put the icon in the folders: drawable-ldpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-hdpi

Comment: Filename is ic_menu_umbrella! or ic_menu_umbrella.png?

Comment: @100rabh I forgot to put the ".png" in the question, sorry about that.

Comment: @MByD I tried putting it in all drawable folders, and then only in the "drawable" folder, the problem still persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Go to the folder  make sure the picture exists.
>
> ---
>
> Open Eclipse with administrative previliges.
>
> ---
>
> Make sure your res folder is complete(contains values and layout folders)
>
> ---
>
> Try using another picture. If it works, the problem is in your picture.
>
> ---
>
> Make sure your picture's filename is **ic_menu_umbrella.png**

Comment: I found out what the problem was, I was linking the icon to the project, not importing it.

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment, so I will answer, try cleaning the project (***Right click on the project -> Android -> Fix Android Project*** and ***Project -> Clean***) before you run it, sometimes I have problems like these.

Comment: I've done this multiple times already, if the manifest has an error in it, Eclipse refuses to generate R.java.

Comment: you said the icon's name is ic_menu_umbrella, you didnt specify if it is a jpg, png or bmp image, maybe it is just unsupported?, try converting the image to png maybe?

Comment: change the icon name and try, just make it myicon.png.

Comment: if changing the name doesn't work, look at the file ownership/permissions

Comment: I had everything right in the manifest and resource files, but was getting a generic icon on the device. Cleaning the project in Eclipse fixed it.